# Iterating the cursor gives an extra NULL document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my code

```
mongoose.connection.on('open', function(err, doc){
    console.log("connection established");

    //**Array Method**
    mongoose.connection.db.collection('simple', function(err, doc){
        if(err){
            console.log("ERROR", err);
        }else{
            doc.find().toArray(function(err, arr){
                console.log("Arr Method", arr);
            })
        }
    })

    //**Cursor Method**
    mongoose.connection.db.collection('simple', function(err, doc){
        if(err){
            console.log("ERROR", err);
        }else{
            var cur = doc.find();
            cur.each(function(err, doc){
                console.log("Cursor item", doc);
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**Output from Array Method**

```
Arr Method 

    [ { _id: 5209340204db66186f93043d, name: 'SUR' },
      { _id: 5209341f04db66186f93043e, name: 'SAT' },
      { _id: 520935c004db66186f93043f, name: 'THI' },
      { _id: 52093b3504db66186f930440, name: 'popo' },
      { _id: 52093cef04db66186f930441, name: 'rorb' } ]
```

**Output from Cursor Method**

```
Cursor item { _id: 5209340204db66186f93043d, name: 'SUR' }
Cursor item { _id: 5209341f04db66186f93043e, name: 'SAT' }
Cursor item { _id: 520935c004db66186f93043f, name: 'THI' }
Cursor item { _id: 52093b3504db66186f930440, name: 'popo' }
Cursor item { _id: 52093cef04db66186f930441, name: 'rorb' }
Cursor item null
```

I have two questions.

1. Why there is an extra log("`Cursor item null`") in the cursor method.
2. If i move my code(`Array method and Cursor method`) out of connection open callback, nothing is
   printed. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. this is really a question about the driver, not mongoose, since you are dropping down to the driver to create Cursor objects.
2. this is [documented behavior](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each) of the driver
3. nothing is printed because you are executing them before the connection to the database is established.